# The Dataflow job appears to be stuck

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The question has now changed a bit.. The main problem is that my code needs oracle libraries but I cant see to use the setup file to run custom commands to set up the oracle client in the workers

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function

import subprocess
from distutils.command.build import build as _build

import setuptools

# This class handles the pip install mechanism.
class build(_build):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    sub_commands = _build.sub_commands + [('CustomCommands', None)]


CUSTOM_COMMANDS = [
    ['sudo','apt-get', 'update'],
    ['sudo','apt-get','--assume-yes','install','unzip'],
['wget','https://storage.googleapis.com/facbeambucketv1/files/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-18.3.0.0.0dbru.zip'],
    ['sudo','unzip','-o', 'instantclient-basic-linux.x64-18.3.0.0.0dbru.zip', '-d' ,'orclbm'],
    ['sudo','apt-get','--assume-yes','install','libaio1'],
    ['sudo','apt-get','--assume-yes','install','tree']  
]


class CustomCommands(setuptools.Command):
    """A setuptools Command class able to run arbitrary commands."""

    def initialize_options(self):
        pass

    def finalize_options(self):
        pass

    def RunCustomCommand(self, command_list):
        print('Running command: %s' % command_list)
        p = subprocess.Popen(
            command_list,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        # Can use communicate(input='y\n'.encode()) if the command run requires
        # some confirmation.
        stdout_data, _ = p.communicate()
        print('Command output: %s' % stdout_data)
        if p.returncode != 0:
            raise RuntimeError('Command %s failed: exit code: %s' % (command_list, p.returncode))

    def run(self):
        for command in CUSTOM_COMMANDS:
            self.RunCustomCommand(command)


# Configure the required packages and scripts to install.
# Note that the Python Dataflow containers come with numpy already installed
# so this dependency will not trigger anything to be installed unless a version
# restriction is specified.
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['numpy','apache_beam','apache_beam[gcp]','cx_Oracle','datetime','google-cloud-bigquery']


setuptools.setup(
    name='orclbm',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='Oraclebm workflow package.',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    cmdclass={
        # Command class instantiated and run during pip install scenarios.
        'build': build,
        'CustomCommands': CustomCommands,
        }
    )
```

However the custom commands are not running. the required packages get installed through. I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: There is not enough info in your description to find the root cause for this. Your job could have been stuck for a multitude of reasons. For example, it could be due to a strain in your resources in general or in one worker in particular. Seeing though as you didn't encounter the problem running locally, this could happen only if you changed the amount and/or key distribution of your input data. Could this be the case?

Comment: Even more: it would be helpful if you edited your question to add any additional warning/error messages (don't rely just on the ones output in job details, go to stackdriver logging and filter by `severity>=WARNING`) as well as your execution graph. Particularly check for stuck steps (wall time is useful for this as well an indication that the amount of output elements does not follow that of input elements).

Comment: @LefterisS actually the input data didnt change at all. This is actually the only error message I got.....Not sure about wall time. The process remains stuck for 1 hr 1 min which according to some post I read has something to do with networking and the compute engines cannot communicate

Comment: It could be, have you set up a separate network where you run the job?

Comment: I am starting the code locally with argument as dataflowrunner...i think it then uses the setup files to create workers but yes the code initates from my local machine...is that a problem?

Comment: the complete log is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qm2pTJL-PMCE_Wk0-DIfnZ7fNlb-M6YI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @LefterisS have changed the question ncan u please help'

Comment: I cannot really figure out something more here, I would suggest that you go ahead and post a comment on google cloud's issue tracker. Moreover, I would suggest that you mark it as private (i.e. file it under [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) component) in order to ensure that only you and googlers can access it. This way you can share your project ID (which by the way, I would advise that you remove from here as it is generally considered Personally Identifiable Information).

Comment: @AbhishekRay I see this message in the logs:
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement re (from orclbm==0.0.1) (from versions: )"

It looks like somewhere there's a dependency on a package named "re".